# Downloaded font is displayed differently in browser

Tags: html, css, fonts

This font Glamora is displayed with more thick than it should be and other weird things
[the font look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9It13.png),
[but is displayed like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NPqwL.jpg)

this is the formatting for that text

```css
.brand h1{
    color: #FEF2DB;
    font-family: Glamora;
    font-size: 230px;
    line-height: 68.1%;
    text-align: center;
    letter-spacing: 0.095em;
}
```

Comment: can you tell us how you define your font to browser.. have you define your font face to your css code ? https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_font-face_rule.asp

Comment: how are you including the fonts?

Comment: It looks OK what is it that looks wrong, is it the T?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There’s probably only one weight of this font, ie. a single style with no bold version or other variants.

By default, `h1` and all other headings are set to be bold, so you are probably getting some faux bolding, created by the browser.

Try adding:

```css
.brand h1 {
  font-family: Glamora;
  /* Etc. */

  font-weight: normal;
}
```

I was able to reproduce your issue, and adding `font-weight: normal;` fixed it:

[image]

This might also have something to do with how the font outlines or how the font file was built, or the fact that it hasn’t been produced as a web font.

The license doesn’t appear to allow converting it into a web font, but it might be worth getting in touch with the designer and seeing if they would produce WOFF and WOFF2 files for you, or modify the license to allow converting the format. That said, that might not impact the issue, and this CSS change does fix it.

Comment: hello sorry for the late reply, i really appreciate your help thankyouu