# Font-family "Rounded-elegant" Bugg on change font-weight

Tags: css, fonts, font-family

when I change the text size to bold, the letters p and q don't take the changes, and reformat to something else.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wROHn.png)

Comment: please include a minimal code example into post for better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

you can get rid of this issue by using a **google fonts**  link in your head of HTML file as you can see in my code I used multiple fonts with the help of [google fonts][1]. After heading to google font website you need to select your font and just need to copy the link and paste in your html file

Here is example:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Archivo+Black&family=Open+Sans:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
```

Hope this solution rectify your code bug
[1]: https://fonts.google.com/

Answer (score 0):

I think this is actually the same issue as this, which includes a before and after code example you can compare to your own: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65161680/864799

There might be an outline issue in the font, combined with some faux bolding. Is it possible the HTML element you have this in is something that is already bolded by default, ex. an `<h1>`?

If so, where you’re applying the font, try adding:

```css
h1 {
  font-family: "The name of the font";
  font-weight: normal;
}
```